# Laravel Validation Two Columns

Tags: laravel, validation

How can I make a combination of two columns unique *together* in request validation for add and update both ? In **minimal** amount of code.

Comment: Welcome! Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service. 
We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. 
You are expected to try to write the code yourself.
Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and 
[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You will need to provide some code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ignore specific id by following syntax

```
'email' => 'unique:table,email_column_to_check,id_to_ignore'
```

for more information you can check official [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#rule-unique)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom validator by extending the Validator class.

```
<?php
// rules define for the particular request.
public function rules() {
    \Validator::extend( 'composite_unique', function ( $attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator ) {

            // remove first parameter and assume it is the table name
            $table = array_shift( $parameters ); 

            // start building the conditions
            $fields = [ $attribute => $value ]; // current field, company_code in your case

            // iterates over the other parameters and build the conditions for all the required fields
            while ( $field = array_shift( $parameters ) ) {
                $fields[ $field ] = $this->get( $field );
            }

            // query the table with all the conditions
            $result = \DB::table( $table )->select( \DB::raw( 1 ) )->where( $fields )->first();

            return empty( $result ); // edited here
        }, 'your custom composite unique key validation message' );

    return [
        'account_name' => 'required|min:5|max:100',
        'legal_name'   => 'max:100',
        // note that here the custom validator is used
        'company_code' => 'required|size:18|composite_unique:accounts,client_id', 
        'client_id'    => 'required|min:1',
    ];
}
```